Drupal user receives "Access Denied" to a public event
I have a group of users of my Drupal site who receive the Drupal "Access Denied" page when accessing an event. The event is public and there's no issue with anonymous users registering for the event.
Event in question: https://secure.gpo.ca/civicrm/event/register?cid=0&reset=1&id=328
THank you

I got a tip to chat.civicrm.org. It seems that my Drupal permissions were set up to allow anonymous users to access resources that authenticated users didn't have access to.
I updated my Drupal permissions to allow authenticated users to access everything that anonymous users had access to.
In the pictures below the first column is the anonymous user the 4th column is the authenticated user
Before:

After:

